# What does "Boeing" mean?

Tags: terminology, boeing

We know about the existence of Boeing planes like the *737*, *747*, and other planes. But where did the name "Boeing" come from?

Comment: It's the noise the plane makes when it bounces, obviously ;)

Comment: @Baldrickk _bounces_? What an untechnical term. You mean, when it _elastically lithobrakes_.

Comment: In light of recent events I submit: Because Obviously Everyone Is Not Going

Comment: It used to be an everyday slang term in Boston and San Francisco. It means "We need better [streetcars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/US_Standard_Light_Rail_Vehicle)".

Comment: Its the noise the stock price of BA makes.

Answer (score 94, accepted):

It's named for one of its founders [William E. Boeing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/William_E._Boeing) which is the American spelling of his father's German surname "Böing".

To answer the question directly: it does not mean anything in particular.

Comment: Well technically Boeing was co-founded by both William Boeing and Conrad Westervelt.  It’s first name was B&W Seaplanes

Comment: I think the "Westervelt 747" has a much nicer ring to it...  Or, "Watch out for that Westervelt B-52 coming to bomb you back into the stone age!"

Comment: Funfact: in German, the word "Bö" or "Windbö" means gust or squall. It's a bit of _nomen est omen_ but that is by pure chance.

Comment: It's not an American spelling so much as a [Middle High German spelling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Germanic_umlaut#Orthography_and_design_history).

Comment: According to [this German newspaper article](https://www.wn.de/Archiv/2010/12/MV-Namensforscher-Boeyng-war-der-Sohn-von-Boie), it means "son of Boie". The origins of Boie are unknown :)

Comment: @PerlDuck I think there's a word for this, 'Nominative Determinism' https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nominative_determinism

Comment: the name "Boing aircraft" might well be appropriate for the company mow :)

Comment: @A.Rowan "The idea that people are drawn to professions that fit their name was suggested by psychologist Carl Jung, citing as an example Sigmund Freud who studied pleasure and whose surname means "joy"." - sounds like Jung was not studying boys at the time, thus discrediting his own theory.

Comment: If it was Böing, that'd mean that basically everyone nowadays pronounces the company name wrong.. ;-)

Comment: @WooShell That is already the case though, since "oe" replaces "ö" in German but is pronounced the same.

Comment: @EricTowers in addition, it's also the official modern German spelling in contexts where the `ö` character is unavailable.

Comment: @user253751 Jung was silly in that, and clearly didn't know the history of surnames in Europe. Originally people took their profession as a surname more often than not, as they were known as "baker" or "plowman" anyway. As quite often children took after their parents' professions, the impression might exist that people chose their profession based on their name rather than the other way around.

Comment: ("Jung" is German for "boy")

Comment: @user253751 No it isn't.  "jung" is an adjective meaning "young".  "Boy" is "der Junge" (note the trailing 'e')

Comment: @MartinBonnersupportsMonica Depending on the local dialect, "Junge" can be instead "Jung" or "Jong". Maybe user253751 stems from a region with that kind of dialect. But you are correct in that "Junge" is correct German.